# Overriding OneToOne with OneToMany Mapping in Hibernate Child Class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance, hibernate-mapping

I have two tables in database orders and offers. Earlier there was @OneToOne mapping between two i.e. for a single order, there was a single offer. Corresponding domains are:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
@DiscriminatorFormula("0")
@DiscriminatorValue("0")
class Order {

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "order", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private Offer offer;

    public Offer getOffer() {
        return this.offer;
    }

    public void setOffer(Offer offer) {     
        this.offer = offer;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "offers")
class Offer {

}
```

Now, i want OneToMany mapping between two i.e. for a single order, there can be multiple offers now. But for that, i want to build new version of Domain so as not to effect existing functionality. As it is OneToMany mapping so i will have to use Set or List. So, effectively, i want did:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("00")
class OrderV2 extends Order {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private Set<Offer> offer;

    public Set<Offer> getOffer() {
        return this.offer;
    }

    public void setOffer(Set<Offer> offer) {        
        this.offer = offer;
    }
}
```

How can i achieve this as currently it is giving me error in getter method as overridden method cannot have different return type.

Comment: Dumb idea. It is either 1-1 OR 1-N not both. An `OrderV2` is also an `Order`, so has BOTH fields now. Design your model right before dirty hacks

Answer (score 0):

Actually your problem is that you are using a field with the same name `offer` as the field in the super class while both have different types, so it will be confusing because you will have the child getter for `Set<Offer>` overriding the parent getter for `Offer`, that's why you get the Exception:

> error in getter method as overridden method cannot have different return type

What you will have to do here is to use a different name for the field in your child class, for example `offers`, so the Model will be correct and Hibernate will correctly map the objects:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("00")
class OrderV2 extends Order {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order1", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private Set<Offer> offers;

    public Set<Offer> getOffers() {
        return this.offers;
    }

    public void setOffers(Set<Offer> offers) {        
        this.offers = offers;
    }
}
```

**Note:**

You need to have two objects of type `Order` in your `Offer` class, one for the mapping of `offer` and the second for the `offers` mapping, notice the `mappedBy = "order1"` in the mapping.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried the same but i get the hibernate error "More than one row with the given identifier was found" when two offers are found for a single order. I think it is happening because offer field (with OneToOne mapping) is getting extended to OrderV2 domain. What i want is to override OneToOne mapping with OneToMany mapping in child class.

Comment: @user2557608 In that case, the short answer is **it is impossible**, as I said the new field in the child class is overriding the one from the parent class, thus they need to have the same type, you can't do that you need another field.

Comment: If you don't need this field in the child class, you just need to remove it from parent class as well, because  fields of super class as meant to be shared between all children.